# Ktor/WebSocket - auto reconnect

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I'm using Ktor Websocket in a multiplatform project (Android/iOS). I saw [auto-retry](https://ktor.io/docs/client-retry.html) for http request, but no option for websocket connection. Does it work with Ktor websocket or any other option?

Comment: The `HttpRequestRetry` plugin retries only HTTP requests. Could you please describe your problem in more detail?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman The app keeps a Web Socket connection to the server. From time to time, the connection is dropped due to client connectivity (ex. switch between wifi/data, connection glitch) or backend (ex. scaling optimization). I would like to implement an auto reconnect logic when it's dropped.

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this.

```kotlin
while (shouldReconnect){
        try {
            httpClient.webSocket(...) {
                //...
            }
        }catch (e:Exception){
            val waitFor=1000L
            println("failed trying in $waitFor ms")
            delay(waitFor)
        }
    }
```